# How to build windows image on azure dev ops hosted agent

Tags: docker, containers, windows, azure-devops, build-pipeline

The host agent pool on azure-devops to build windows container, `Hosted Windows Container` is running Windows Server version 1803.

But I want to deploy on Windows Server 2019, so instead of using Microsoft `:1803` images, I'm building from images tagged `:ltsc2019`.

How can I build my `:ltsc2019` images on azure-devops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Microsoft added a new hosted agent: `Hosted Windows 2019 with VS 2019`.

So you should use this image to build for `windows-1809` or `windows-2019`

Source : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent

---

## Old answer:

FWIW, I ended up creating a windows server 2019 vm on azure to act as a build agent.

Could not manage to build 2019 image in any of the hosted agent pools.